# pip install / pytz versioning conflict?

Tags: pip, protocol-buffers, versioning, pytz

I ran `pip install protobuf==2.6.1` as part of a project's `install` script on an Ubuntu 12.04 VM. This yields the following error:

```
Collecting protobuf==2.6.1
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz (188kB)
    100% |################################| 188kB 2.5MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Installed /tmp/pip-build-AnwMIr/protobuf/.eggs/google_apputils-0.4.2-py2.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 20, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-AnwMIr/protobuf/setup.py", line 200, in 
        "Protocol Buffers are Google's data interchange format.",
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1074, in best_match
        dist = working_set.find(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 711, in find
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req)
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pytz 2011k (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pytz>=2010'))
```

Using `pip install -r requirements.txt` yields the same error.

I have `pip 7.1.2`, and have `protobuf 2.6.1` on other Ubuntu 12.04 VMs with similar (not identical) lists of installed packages. Pip freeze says `pytz===2011k`. (Note the *triple* equals.)

`pip-conflict-checker` reports only one conflict, seemingly unrelated to both `pytz` and `protobuf`:

```
$ pipconflictchecker
--------------------------------------------------
 Conflicts Detected
--------------------------------------------------
 - python-dateutil(2.1) pandas(<2)
```

Why is pip flagging `pytz===2011k` and `pytz>=2010` as being in conflict?

I would like to list all my pip requirements in a single "requirements.txt". Is there a way to do this without triggering the above error? I have no explicit, direct requirements on `pytz` itself.

I was also able to get `protobuf` to install with an explicit `pip install 2012b0`, but **not** using `pip install -r requirements.txt` for a requirements.txt with both `protobuf==2.6.1` and `pytz>=2015`.

Potentially-relevant links:

- Deprecated pytz versioning workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1224858
- Example of a straightforward VersionConflict and pip conflict checker: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/918
- PEP 440 / Python versioning https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440 Includes special note for pytz versions https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#olson-database-versioning and description of the '===' https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#arbitrary-equality
- pip development thread on dependency checking / resolution https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping someone comes up with a better solution, but that might have to wait on pip providing real tools for conflict resolution, rather than its current "silently take whatever it finds first" approach. (See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#requirements-files ) The particular issue is likely also complicated by pip's apparent inability to parse pytz 2011k's version number. (I think that's the meaning of the "===", but I haven't found explicit confirmation in pip's docs.)

In the meantime, I seem to have two options:

- Explicitly specify a version of pytz in requirements.txt
- Rearrange the order of the dependencies in requirements.txt

Both options suffer from the same issue: There is no way to get the necessary data ([preferred version of pytz] or [preferred order]) other than one of these:

- manually parsing my full dependency tree
- trial-and-error

I'm suggesting this "answer" as a placeholder / guide / workaround for myself & others. I don't consider it to be "acceptable", since it's brittle: If I want to keep pytz up-to-date, I have to monitor their release schedule and potentially repeat the above process any time either pytz releases an update or I add / remove a dependency involving pytz.

Watch this thread in hopes of getting a real solution: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988

Answer (score 0):

On my MAC EL-Capitan I had the similar errors using python version 2.6 with the error below

`bash# ./configure   CXXFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated-declarations
bash# make
...
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (putz 2012d (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('pytz>=2010'))
make[2]: *** [../3rdparty/protobuf-2.6.1/python/dist/protobuf-2.6.1-py2.6.egg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`

**Solution**

Changed python version > 2.6 as it seems the is a version compatibility issue of pytz with 2.6

However python3.4 fails while using the ./configure script stops at
`.checking whether python3.4 version >= 2.6... configure: error: too old`

So I advise you stick with python2.7
`bash# ./configure   CXXFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated-declarations PYTHON_VERSION=2.7
bash# make`